# Combining covariances

Tags: correlation, covariance, sample, population, pooling

Imagine we have one sample (n=40) from a population on 2 variables, for which we estimate the covariance (say, 0.1). If we would have another sample (n=10) from the same population, and we estimate the covariance to be 0.2, what would we expect to be the covariance in the population?

Would it be:
(4/5 * 0.1) + (1/5 * 0.2) = 0.12?

That is, could we weigh the covariances according to the sample size?

If yes, how to combine the data into having a covariance of 0.12, since copying one data below the other won't do.

Comment: And no, this is not a homework question.

Comment: You need to take the means of the two samples into account. Consider the simpler case of one variable. If different samples give different (conditional) means and variances, then the combined variance is the (weighted) average of the conditional variances plus the variance of the conditional mean. A similar effect will arise with covariance: the two covariances are likely computed using different means, $(\mu_{X,2},\mu_{Y,2})$ instead of $(\mu_{X,1},\mu_{Y,1})$, and so just a weighted sum of the covariances will not do either.

Comment: Put another way, if you simply merged the two samples into a single sample $(n=50)$, the covariance that you will compute for the merged sample will typically not work out to be $0.12$.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773857/merging-covariance-from-two-sets-to-create-new-covariance